# I have some credentials in DB that I want to use in node,how to share credentials in all required files in node

Tags: node.js, express

I have some credentials in DB that I want to use in node , but it's required in many file ,how can I share these in all required files in node

Comment: What do you mean by _credentials in DB_ ? Is the credentials to connect to the database ?

Comment: no i have some mws credentials , that i need when i will request to mws server

Answer (score 0):

You can add a load file before settings

```
//load.js

db.Table.findAll().then(function(rows) {
  fs.writeFileSync('settings.json', JSON.stringify(rows));
  require('./app'); // app is loaded after settings written to file 
})

//app.js

require('settings.json')

//api/controller.js

require('../settings.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option:

**Step 0 :** Install `config` by `npm` (`npm install config --save`).

**Step 1 :** Create a folder name `config`.

**Step 2 :** Add a file `default.json`.

**Step 3 :** Write your all `credentials` like below. (in `default.json`)

```
{
    "appName": "abcdefgh",
    "appCode": "ABC",
    "mongodb": {
        "url": "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/my_db"
    },
    "server": {
        "port": 8081
    },
    "tokenValidation": "7d",
    "emailValidation": "1d",
    "auth": {
        "user": "abcdefgh@gmail.com",
        "pass": "abcdefgh"
    },
   "apiKeys": {
    "android": "BA006D7537A077C852BCB34F7219B8D5069CCB",
    "ios":     "FB499A4FF77901AFCD2278457658DAA304D3F2",
    "web":     "25BDD8EC59070421FDDE3C5711A285884E979F"
   },
  "aws": {
        "credentials": {
            "accessKeyId": "abcdefghijklmnop",
            "secretAccessKey": "abcdefghijklmnop/YS",
            "signatureVersion": "v4"
        },
        "s3": {
            "bucket": "abcdefghijklmnop",
            "region": "us-west-2"
        }
    }
```

}

**Step 4 :** If you want to access any credentials then you need to require config. (`config` should be installed by npm : `npm install config --save`) and access any credential with below code:

```
var config=require('config');
console.log(config.get('aws.credentials.accessKeyId'));
console.log(config.get('apiKeys.android'));
console.log(config.get('tokenValidation'));
```